# How can I fix errors in django?

Tags: python, django

I've tried everything I can, but I can't fix this error. I am a beginner and imitated what was in the book. Give me a hand.

This is my **fistsite/urls.py**  source code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/polls', views.polls, name='polls'),
    path('/admin', views.admin, name='admin')
]
```

This is my **polls/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/result/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

But there was an error.

[image]

And this is my project.

[image]

Help me!

Comment: Please show the source for views.py too.

Comment: try `from polls import views` this

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please when showing errors, always show the entire stack trace not as an image but as a code snippet or quote. The important parts of your error are missing: Which line and which file is raising the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error occurs in `firstsite/urls.py` because of the line `from . import views`.

There is no file `firstsite/views.py` according to your image of the project structure. Removing the import statement or importing from somewhere else should solve this issue.

---

Next time add the whole stacktrace, not just the last error message. That way it is easy to see which line raises the error.

---

If you are trying to import `polls/views.py` into `firsite/urls.py`, you could try something like `from ..polls import views`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't import views of an `app` into main project's `urls.py`.. JUST try excluding the 'from . import views`from the`fistsite/urls.py`..
It should work now..

try executing below code..

**fistsite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/polls', views.polls, name='polls'),
    path('/admin', views.admin, name='admin')
]
```

**polls/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/result/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

or create all the `view` functions inside the `app` and `include(app.urls)` into the main project's `urls.py'..

Answer (score 0):

I think you're adding the url in the wrong file. There are two url.py in the project. The one you have above should be the one inside the 'polls' directory and should look like this:

`polls/url.py`:

```
    from django.urls import url, include

    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url('^polls/', views.polls, name='polls'),
        url('^admin/', views.admin, name='admin')
    ]
```

the `firstsite/urls.py` inside the firstsite should look like this:

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
         url(r'', include('polls.urls')),
         url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin')
    ]
```

The difference is that the first one is the urls for the App `polls` the second one is for the whole project. You can have many apps inside a project.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "from . import views" in the wrong url.py.You should write it in polls/urls.py only.

When you write "." Django will not look in inner app Polls.

If you want to do it change your code like below:

In fistsite/url.py:

''''

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/polls', views.polls, name='polls'),
    path('/admin', views.admin, name='admin')
]
```

''''

and **polls/urls.py**

''''

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/result/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

''''